# Punctuation in amsthm Theorem headers

Tags: amsthm, amsart

If I number theorems by sections, then amsthm numbers the first theorem in the first section as

```
Theorem 1.1.
```

How can I change this to

```
Theorem 1-1
```

?

Comment: A quick method is `\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@thmcountersep}{-} \makeatother`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Many thanks Barbara! Unfortunately, in my case, this does not seem to work.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done and what the problem is. Why should we have to try and guess your code?

Comment: As I write below, what Mico proposes works just fine. That's good enough for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've set up a theorem-like environment called, say, `theorem`, via

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

then all you need to add is the instruction

```
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\thesection-\arabic{theorem}}
```

As per @barbarabeeton's comment, if you want to change the numbering style for *all* theorem-like environments, it would actually be much easier to execute

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\@thmcountersep}{-} 
\makeatother
```

in the preamble.

---

If, in addition, you also want to suppress the `.` ("dot", aka "full stop") after the composite theorem number, I suggest you execute the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart} % or some other suitable docuemnt class
%% \usepackage{amsthm} % not needed if 'amsart' doc. class is in use

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@thmcountersep}{-} % per @barbarabeeton's suggestion
\patchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{} % optional
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\begin{theorem} Bla bla bla. \end{theorem}
\begin{definition} Ble ble ble. \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks Mico! Barbara's solution does not work in my case. I don't know why. Modifying the `\thetheorem` command does however work. Another method to remove the final dot is to use a custom theoremstyle.

Comment: @220284 - The `\patchcmd{\@thm}{...}{...}{}{}` method suggested above is certainly a global-scople method.  I would advocate the `\newtheoremstyle` route if I wanted to remove the dot just for some theorem-like environments but not for all.